# mysql where condition doesn't show results in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I got a mysql query which works but not in PHP

```
SELECT rev_date, rev_currency, SUM(rev_amount) AS total_amount
FROM daily_revenue
WHERE YEAR(rev_date) = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND MONTH(rev_date) = MONTH(CURDATE())
GROUP BY rev_currency, YEAR(rev_date), MONTH(rev_date)
```

I tried it in PHP until it worked and it looks like it doesn't like the where and group by conditions:

this fails:

```
WHERE YEAR(rev_date) = YEAR(CURDATE())
```

this works:

```
WHERE rev_date = YEAR(CURDATE())
```

but doesn't give me the results I want.

Any ideas?

Comment: what is table description ?  what is rev_date type?

Comment: how are you running it when it works? and what php?

Answer (score 0):

I added mysql error (should have done that right away)
which made it clear, i had to do this:

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));
```

now it works.